# Как сделать врага который способен прокладывать маршрут по карте с препятствиями в unity 2d?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть игра в unity 2d, и мне нужно сделать врага который сам прокладывает маршрут по карте с объектами и ело минимум ресурсов т.к игра для андроид, сейчас я сделал чтоб он запоминал его последнюю позицию в которой он замечен. Например, враг бежит за игроком но игрок скрывается за стеной, враг должен проложить маршрут по карте чтоб тот не врезался в стену или другие объекты и если он на последнем месте где замечен игрок но игрока нет поблизости, враг осматривает окружение.

Comment: ___NavMesh?____

Comment: A* Pathfinding? (минимум ресурсов)

Answer (score 1):

A* Pathfinding Project: https://arongranberg.com/astar/

Готовый юнити ассет, имеет как платную, так и бесплатную(но ограниченную, конечно же) версию. Работает, как понятно из названия, по алгоритму A*